# How do I save offline a PDF from the browser?

Tags: file

Given a [PDF available online](http://www.ibiblio.org/julesverne/books/jce%20revd%20edn.pdf), how in the world do I save it locally on the iPad? Why is this so counter-intuitive, if not downright impossible, when the iPad is a very nice e-reader?

Answer (score 1):

- load the PDF in Safari
- tap once
- tap on "Open in iBooks…" on top right

The PDF will be opened (and stored) in iBooks then